# Display both regular and discounted fees in events page

Tags: civievent, price-sets, discounts

is there a way to display both regular and discounted fees in an event page?

[image]

I would want to put the regular price under our Early Bird price.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable ask - ie that folk should be able to see all the prices so they know what they are saving by going Early Bird. I tested on dmaster to confirm and agree that the above is what I also get at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=1 though I am not even seeing the 'earlybird' text that i added at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/manage/fee#/volunteer/manage/0

Comment: Hi @petednz-fuzion, yes, exactly! We've accomplished this already by tinkering with the Event Page class. I'll submit an answer as soon as I have some free time.

Answer (score 2):

For a no-coding solution, you can use a price set, and have the early-bird price options located just above their counterparts, but with the "Expire On" value set.